# Check output of JsonPath with Hamcrest Matchers

Tags: java, junit, spring-test, hamcrest, jsonpath

I wrote Spring controller Junits. 
I used JsonPath to fetch all IDs from JSON using `["$..id"]`.

I have following as test method :

```
mockMvc.perform(get(baseURL + "/{Id}/info", ID).session(session))
    .andExpect(status().isOk()) // Success
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$..id").isArray()) // Success
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$..id", Matchers.arrayContainingInAnyOrder(ar))) // Failed
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$", Matchers.hasSize(ar.size()))); // Success
```

Following is the data that I passed :-

```
List<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
ar.add("ID1");
ar.add("ID2");
ar.add("ID3");
ar.add("ID4");
ar.add("ID5");
```

I got failure message as:-

```
Expected: [<[ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,ID5]>] in any order
     but: was a net.minidev.json.JSONArray (<["ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5"]>)
```

**Question is :** How to handle JSONArray with `org.hamcrest.Matchers;` Is there any simple way to use *jsonPath*.

Settings :- `hamcrest-all-1.3 jar` , `json-path-0.9.0.jar`, `spring-test-4.0.9.jar`

Answer (score 13):

`JSONArray` is not an array but an `ArrayList` (i.e., a `java.util.List`).

Thus you should not use the following:

`Matchers.arrayContainingInAnyOrder(...)`

But rather:

`Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(...)`.

Answer (score 11):

You should use:

`(jsonPath("$..id", hasItems(id1,id2))`

Comment: Could you provide the exact static import for `jsonPath(...)` ?

Comment: @kiltek org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath

Answer (score 1):

Your example is for String items. Here's a wider solution for complex POJOs:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.items.[?(@.property in ['" + propertyValue + "'])]",hasSize(1)))
```

See the official documentation here: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 0):

encounter same issue, resolved by below

```
Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(new String[]{"ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5"})
```